# What are attributes I can put in a Building, Car, and Bicycle class?

Tags: attributes

For building I can think of height, area covered, number of people inside, number of floors, and number of windows.
For car there's amount of gas, and number of seats.
Can't think of any unique ones for bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

any property that you want your classes to have.
It basically depends where you want to use these and how later you want to retrieve this information and for what purpose
say

- Class Car

  you can have 
  current speed 
  colour 
  year of make 
  market price
  make
  number of cylinders 
  may be a print function to get all this
  information?
- Building
  land size
  year of build
  commercial or residential
  occupied or vaccant
  name of city located
- Bicycle
  make
  material
  type
  color
  year of make
  number of gears

It could be anything you want to use later in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Type of frame, type of brakes, racing or casual..
I am not sure if this question belongs here.